# Is it possible to emit signals to a different tree?

Tags: signals, godot, gdscript

I am currently making a simple tree which looks like this :

> MainNode (Parent) -> Character (Child)

MainNode can add child or free one from any files such as maps (i.e. terrain.tscn) or events (i.e. event.tscn). All events and maps will be stored in a dictionary for easy usage. The codes would look like this :

```
func loadNewScene(key):
   # load the corresponding tscn file from dictionary
   add_child(instanced_scene)

func freeScene(key):
   # find the corresponding target node using key
   target.queue_free()

func _ready():
   # load Mainmenu.tscn
   loadNewScene("Mainmenu")
```

My problem begins when I press start in the Mainmenu.tscn. If I had Mainmenu.tscn as a child (in default), I can always emit a signal for confirming the player press the button to fire a signal to proceed to the next scene, such as :

```
func _on_Button_pressed():
    var target_scene = "Opening Scene"
    freeScene(current_scene)
    loadNewScene(target_scene)
```

But since the node isn't actually in the MainNode (It will be added as a child after _ready() ), I can't find a way to emit a signal from "Mainmenu.tscn" to MainNode, because initially it's not in the MainNode's tree.

Is there a way to make a signal to a different tree? Or is there a alternative solve for this?

Comment: Signals are inherited from `Object` and can be connected and emitted even when the target `Node` is not in the scene tree. I recommend updating your post with the code that is causing the issue and describing your desired outcome.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are a bit confused about what a `tree` is in Godot.

By default you have one [SceneTree](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_scenetree.html#class-scenetree), which holds the game loop. And scenes can enter or leave that tree (by calling respectively `add_child` and `remove_child` on a node inside the tree).

Now, I believe the best way to solve your is issue is by giving all your modules (any node which is not `MainNode` if I understood your design properly) the responsibility to call whatever they need from `MainNode`. In other words, your modules could depend on `MainNode` but not the other way around.

It means that `MainMenu` could have code that looks like that:

```
var _main_node: MainNode

func _enter_tree():
    _main_node = get_parent()

func _on_Button_pressed():
    var target_scene = "Opening Scene"
    _main_node.loadNewScene(target_scene)
    _main_node.freeScene(_main_node.current_scene)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly you try to connect to a child signal dynamically at runtime. You can do that in code:

[Connecting to signals in code](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/getting_started/step_by_step/signals.html#connecting-signals-in-code)

Secondly I believe you try to use this to change the level. I believe a more Godotic way can be found here:

[How to load and change scenes](https://godotengine.org/qa/24773/how-to-load-and-change-scenes)